# Squid caching blocking "video/*" as file type

Tags: squid

I'm trying to block a file type (video/*) in Squid (Cache) instead of blocking individual extensions.

Is it something possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an ACL of the type [rep_mime_type](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) and set it to your regex. Then, use the [http_reply_access directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/http_reply_access/) to block access.

```
acl deny_rep_mime_anyvideo rep_mime_type video/.*
http_reply_access deny deny_rep_mime_anyvideo
```